# NSOutlineView doesn't call the data source methods

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview, appkit

Simple problem: `NSOutlineView` doesn't call the data source methods.

Datasource is correctly wired in Interface Builder to the correct class object.

It's cell based.
I've implemented many NSOUtlineViews before, not sure what's going wrong with this one.

What could be the reason?

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item
- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item
```

Comment: Datasource should be wired to an object from the xib, not to a file.

Comment: The connections are going to `File's owner` or View/Window class?

Comment: @Astoria the connection are going to an Custom Class object that I've added to the xib file. It's not the File Owner

Comment: @Cristik Yes, of course an object in the xib, which is a class in the project.

Comment: How does your code get a reference to the delegate object?

Comment: @PhillipMills I haven't; set the delegate object yet. Data Source only.

Comment: @Astoria I've also tried to add the datasource methods to the File Owner and bind it as data source: it doesn't work.

Comment: @Patrick set File's Owner as data source and try to call `[outlineView reloadData]` in arbitrary moment (i.e. on button click). Doesn't it really call methods?

Comment: @Astoria I did as you said. A button is triggering reloadData. IT doesn't work. reloadData is called correctly, the table is not nil. Datasource is targeting the File's Owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK after few hours I figured out. This method is not optional as I thought:

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
```

It must be implemented, or the other ones won't be called, as written in documentation, below, in little.

> IMPORTANT While this method is marked as @optional in the protocol,
>   you must implement this method if you are not providing the data for
>   the outline view using Cocoa bindings.